# In Visual Studio2019 how to setup the codehighlightcolors in the editor for Classes/Parameter/Functions etc.?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, settings, color-scheme

I watched a youtube video about Blazor and noticed that my color highlighting of my code in the texteditor was different from the video. In the video much more codebits had different colors then it is the case in my Visual Studio 2019 setup.
My code has some coloring but its alot of white lines instead of every codebit differend colorsetting (Class/Function/Parameter/...).

Please see the attached jpeg!

[image]

How can I also have those color settings from the video (jpeg left side is what I want // right side is what I have) in my VS? Is that a "plugin" to download or where can I find the settings for that?

In VS I checked Tools-Options- and then tried different dropdown menues but could not find the place for these settings (kind of lost because there are so much options)!

Thanks for helping me to get more colors in my code/life :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if that is totaly the same thing I saw but it it close to what I wanted.

You can install a Extension to VS via Marketplace. I installed this:
[Enhanced Syntax Highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting&ssr=false)

From Stanislav Kuzmich